MacBook Pro webcam won't work on Ubuntu 22.04, kernel 6.5.0-35-generic
The built-in webcam of my MacBookPro 2015 is not recognized by Linux.
The previous solution relied on the github repo facetimehd-firmware, which the dev does not seem to maintain anymore...
Reiterating the previous solution
(worked for kernels 5.9.XXX...)
Upon installing the driver (manual by the developer: https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd/wiki/Installation#get-started-on-ubuntu), I get:
usr1@myubuntu ~/bcwc_pcie$ make
make -C /lib/modules/6.5.0-35-generic/build M=/home/usr1/bcwc_pcie modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-35-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc-12 (Ubuntu 12.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 12.3.0
  You are using:           
  CC [M]  /home/usr1/bcwc_pcie/fthd_ddr.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc-12: not found
make[3]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:251: /home/usr1/bcwc_pcie/fthd_ddr.o] Error 127
make[2]: *** [/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-35-generic/Makefile:2039: /home/usr1/bcwc_pcie] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:234: __sub-make] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-6.5.0-35-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:12: all] Error 2


Do you have any idea what to do?

I should have read the error message more carefully: it reports the missing gcc-2 dependancy.
/bin/sh: 1: gcc-12: not found

This alone may have worked; but there is a nice installation script in the pull request of the driver repo: https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd/issues/294
that worked perfectly smooth!
Even Cheese works now! (Albeit quite laggy)
The driver installation script
Credits to   Cristian R. Olmos 
#!/bin/bash

#Adaptación a Fuente: https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd/wiki/Get-Started#firmware-extraction
# Taken from https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd/issues/294

sudo apt install xz-utils curl cpio git make gcc gcc-12
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic git kmod libssl-dev checkinstall

printf "Cloning the driver repo\n";
git clone https://github.com/patjak/bcwc_pcie.git
cd bcwc_pcie

printf "Cloning the firmware facetimeHD repo into the driver repo\n";
git clone https://github.com/patjak/facetimehd-firmware.git

printf "Backing up...\n";
mv firmware firmware__
mv facetimehd-firmware firmware

cd bcwc_pcie/firmware

printf "Compiling firmware\n";
make
printf "done\n\n";

printf "Installing firmware\n";
sudo make install
printf "done\n\n";

cd ..

printf "Compiling driver\n";
make
printf "done\n\n";

printf "Installing driver\n";
sudo make install
printf "done\n\n";

printf "Running depmod\n";
sudo depmod
printf "done\n\n";

printf "modprobe remove bdc_pci (if it exists)\n";
sudo modprobe --remove --quiet bdc_pci
printf "done\n\n";

printf "Loading driver\n";
sudo modprobe facetimehd
printf "done\n\n";


Later the info in the link may not be there. If the answer is relying on the info at that link a good idea is put that info in your answer.

Well, indeed. I copy-pasted his script here!
